# Is there a connection between Syrio Forel and Melisandre?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S08E03 Melisandre says something to Arya that calls back to season one to motivate her. specifically she asks

> What do we say to the God of Death?

Arya seeing her purpose clearly is responds

> Not Today

Are Syrio and Melisandre connected somehow? If so how? Or is this just Melisandre magic?

Comment: No, they're not connected, Melisandre just seems to conveniently know what she needs to know, without explanation.

Comment: @Möoz It may be that this is common culture in *Essos*, where both Syrio and Melisandre hail from (though they come from different cities/regions in Essos).

Comment: @Möoz There is too an explanation!

Comment: @AndresF. I'd doubt that. "Valar Morghulis/Dohaeris" is to be seen as 'common', so it is repeated often, so is "A Lannister _always_ pays his debts", but the "..not today" is mentioned **once** only. It's too specific to be a common phrase.

Comment: @Möoz I got the impression that while not as common as Valar Morghulis, it's common in Essos, especially those familiar with the Faceless Men and/or their culture. [This wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Syrio_Forel) describes Syrio's phrase as "a warrior's belief". Braavosi also come from everywhere, and the city was founded by former slaves, and didn't Melisandre claim she was a former slave? Finally, I see links between the phrase and the House of Black & White, who claim the Lord of Light is an aspect of Death. I see many reasons why Melisandre would know that saying.

Comment: @Möoz Melisandre also receives visions, allegedly by the Lord of Light. She sees many things (and is mistaken about as many, of course). She could also have "seen" this saying of the people of Bravos, especially if it turns out it would have helped Arya. Seers see things ;)

Comment: This is just Bravosi for *"Not today, Satan"* :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no connection between Syrio and Melisandre. As @Mooz put in comments "Melisandre just seems to conveniently know what she needs to know, without explanation".

This is same as when she uttered Ygritte's word "You know nothing, Jon Snow" to Jon.

Comment: Without explanation? We know she has visions in the flames. Sometimes she doesn't interpret them correctly but that doesn't make them fake. It is not impossible that she saw those interactions in the flames.

Comment: When I initially made that comment, I intended it to mean that she knows in some way that's not explained. Visions? Flame-chat? Weirwood dream? Something else?... It doesn't matter, she knows in some way, but we just don't know _how_. It's also convenient because, well, she pulls it out of nowhere.

Comment: I am sure she sees things in pieces, probably she saw Aryas face, then heard Syrio 
 say "What do we say to the God of Death", and then Arya replying back, and all, the Lord of Light just had to give her the signal. She don't exactly have to know Syrio

Comment: Her visions are not as vivid(interactive?) as Bran's. They show her glimpses not the actual conversations between two people. I dont remember any passage from the books/show explaining how she knows the conversations(dialogs exchanged) between two people.

Comment: @Skooba We have no clear idea of what her limitations are, or where exactly her power comes from.  This makes for a very confusing character, since she can basically just pop out and know things / do things that are conveniently appropriate to the moment.  Sure, we have some vague pseudo-information, what with R'hllor, visions and leeches and blood and all - but nothing that would allow us to expect something from her, or to be surprised by her.  She just kind of does / knows things occasionally as the show's writers wish.  Thus, *without explanation*.

Comment: @MishaR Did you read my answer? Her powers would be no more surprising than Bran's and I don't see all "there is no explanation" with him. There are other prophets to, Maggie the Frog, Qaithe. Even Varys just always chalks up his knowledge to his little birds but really that's just an excuse to know things albeit a physical one.

Comment: @Skooba Sure, but the question is about Melisandre. One confusing character doesn't explain another - although I would argue that Varys' "birds" are overpowered, but decidedly less narratively confusing. Either way, the fact that you don't see "there is no explanation" with Bran or Varys is not especially relevant for answering this question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no real connection between them. We do not seem them physically cross paths while both are alive.

Melisandre is from Asshai and is worshipper of R'hllor. This following there are two gods, the god of fire/light (R'hllor) and the god of ice/darkness (the Great Other).

Syrio is from Bravos and seems to practice the religion of the Faceless Men. In that following there is only "one" god, the god of death (although he has many faces and as we learn from Jaqen the "red god" is one of them).

However there is a good reason that Melisandre knows words spoken between characters when no one else was around... she has visions in the flames! She can see events in the past, present, and future. While she doesn't always interpret them correctly there is no reason why she could not see these specific interactions and repeat a single line she heard.

> [Melisandre] When I gaze into the flames, I can see through stone and earth, and find the truth within men's souls. I can speak to kings long dead and children not yet born, and watch the years and seasons flicker past, until the end of days.
>
> [Jon] Are your fires never wrong?
>
> [Melisandre] Never ... though we priests are mortal and sometimes err, mistaking this must come for this may come.
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons, Chapter 3, Jon I*</sub>